# Removing/changing admin password on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, passwords, password-recovery

My senior parents forgot their Administrator account on their Windows 10 desktop.

I can boot Kali on it and dump the password hash, but trying to crack it didn't succeed, apparently they had some looooong password.

I cannot use `chntpw` or similar tools, since this Win10 is after Anniversary update and `chntpw` doesn't work any more.

Is there any other way of Removing/changing admin password on Windows 10 from Linux?

I really want to avoid reinstalling the whole OS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I used chntpw on a Win10 21H2 machine yesterday and it certainly seems to have worked.

Comment: If Microsoft Account, you can change the password at Microsoft Live.  That works. If local Account, you can also change the password with Pogo Stick ...... https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: @reflog - Why can’t you enable the default built-in Administrator account?

Comment: @user1686 - I've tried several times with chntpw, resetting password doesn't do anything.

Comment: @John `ntpasswd` doesn't work with new SAM as far as I understand

Comment: @Ramhound can you elaborate?

Comment: If al the above does not work, you may need to reinstall Windows and keep a record of passwords.

Comment: @reflog - What part of my question wasn’t clear? Windows has a built-in Administrator account. Are you able to enable it?